# How to Get a Value from Firebase Using Ionic 4

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

Sorry to ask. I'm just a noob here :(
Using Ionic 4 + Firebase, just for learning, say I have a button on html with a (click) function and want to be able to get a value!!! Banging my head on the wall!
example:

```
Firebase DB:
collection "Places"
doc: 
id: 1
name: somename
```

want to click the button and by hard-coding the id, I want to alert(somename)

when I click I get [object Object], cannot get into the object.
code:

```
export class Tab4Page implements OnInit {
  lugar: AngularFirestoreCollection<Places>;
  lugares: Observable<Places[]>;
  constructor(private _angFireStore: AngularFirestore) {
    this.lugar = this._angFireStore.collection('Places');
    this.lugares = this.lugar.valueChanges();
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  //this is the function
  pruebaF1() {
    alert(this.lugares);  //What's next here???!!
  }
}
```

sorry I can't get it.

do not know how to further dig into this.lugares to hardcode an id and just get a value: say, get nombre where id = 1, then nombre = somename
and if I say id = 2, then nombre = the name that's in the db for that doc.

not angular wise :(

Thanks in advance!!!! :)

Comment: anyone? please? is my question too dumb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you are genuinely trying here. I see scenarios like this quite a lot and always wonder how people got this far in the first place. I'm curious, are you following a guide or just trying random bits of code?

The best thing to do is to follow some getting started tutorials which will walk you through each of the steps of the basics. Do what they want to teach you first, and then afterwards start building your own by editing bits until you find yourself writing the whole thing without problems.

[This seems like an interesting guide](https://www.thecodecampus.de/blog/getting-started-firestore-angularfire2/), or the [official angularfire2 docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md).

Basically you are missing some concepts which would be best explained in a well written tutorial. What you get back with your code so far is an observable. That could be used in the front end with something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of lugares | async">
    {{ item.name }} is {{ item.price }} (assuming these properties exist)
  </li>
</ul>
```

But what you are actually asking is not this. You are writing code to access a collection, but to get a single one `where id = 1` type query is a document, which would be more like:

```
this.placeRef = this.afs.collection(''Places'', ref => ref.where('id', '==', '1'));
```

But then that still gives you the missing understanding of what to do with it after. I think the best thing is to dig into the getting started documentation.

BTW the original tag you had, firebase realtime database is the old database and a very different technology, so if you are searching for information you need to make sure you are using the correct "firestore" search term.